# Запретить переносы строк

Tags: html, css

Каким образом запретить переносы строк, чтобы текст сам обрезался и не уходил под картинку? `white-space: nowrap` наполовину помогает, но текст не обрезается и остаётся под картинкой.

Примерно что-то такое должно получиться:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/0gx4ugg4/2/

```css
.clearfix {display: block;}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {display: table; line-height: 0; content: '';}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}

.fl_l {float: left;}
.fl_r {float: right;}

.profile {}
.profile .photo {width: 54px}
.profile .photo img {max-width: 46px}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="fl_l photo">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y818.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="fl_l info">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magnaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Проблему решил сам, неактуально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше вот так, текст не будет вылазить за страницу и обрезаться троеточием:

```
.clearfix {
    display: flex;
}

.info {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Пример [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzj60tka/1/)

Answer (score 3):

```
.one-line
{    
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: @ModaL https://jsfiddle.net/0gx4ugg4/3/  но это глупости